# Standard way to populate a member vector inside a class with class instances in c++

Tags: c++, vector

Given two classes for example `Equation` and `Term`,  where the `Equation` has a member vector of type `Term`

**Term.h**

```
class Term
{
    public:
          Term();
          Term(string inputTerm);
    private:
          string termValue;
}
```

**Term.cpp**

```
#include "Term.h"

Term::Term()
{
    //default ctr
}


Term::Term(string inputTerm)
{
    termValue = inputTerm;
}
```

**Equation.h**

```
#include 'Term.h'

class Equation
{
    public:
           Equation(string inputEQ)

    private:
           vector<string> termStrings;  //The input for the constructors of a Term
           vector<Term> theTerms; // The vector I wish to populate

}
```

**Equation.cpp**

```
#include "Equation.h"    

Equation::Equation(string inputEQ)
{
    while(parsing inputEQ for individual terms)
    {
        //This is where the vector of strings is populated
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < termStrings; i++)
    {
        //Loop the same number of times as number of terms
        //This is where I wish to "push_back" an instance
        //of a term with the according termString value to 
        //my vector "theTerms" however I recieve an error 
        //when I attempt this.

        //updated:
        Term * aTerm = new Term( termString[i] );
        theTerms.push_back( aTerm );

    }

}
```

What is the most logical way to populate the vector of terms in a loopable method?

Comment: What error do you receive when using push_back?

Comment: I have received several different errors depending on how I create new term objects.  I have also tried creating a single instance of a term trying to change the values and then pushing it back again. Neither method has yet to work for me.

Comment: Even if you have gotten multiple different errors, you should at least include one or two examples of what errors you get and what code gave you those errors.

Comment: Pick one method and show us the error. Flailing about guessing then not showing us _any_ information is pointless.

Comment: I will update it when I have a chance I just thought there was some standard way to populate a vector with instances of a class

Comment: You're adding a `Term` pointer to your vector, when you've declared it as `vector<Term>`. That won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that your vector is containing concrete objects, and `Term` does not have a copy or move constructor. You have two options for a solution:

1. Use `vector<shared_ptr<Term>>` instead. This will store pointers to your `Term` objects and allow you to directly manipulate items in your vector.
2. Add a copy constructor `Term::Term(Term&)` to your `Term` class. This will allow items to be copied into and out of your vector.

Which approach is appropriate for your scenario will depend on how you use the `Term` objects. If you need to pass around instances, then the first approach is the one you want. If you want to make sure items in your list are invariant so you need to work on copies, then the second approach is the right one.

Comment: I believe this will do what I am looking for

Comment: In the code OP has posted, `Term` is trivially copiable, and a copy constructor will be automatically generated. I feel like recommending to use `shared_ptr` here is a bad idea, as it appears OP doesn't fully grasp the concept of plain pointers, let alone smart pointers and their implications. Simply changing the `Equation` constructor functionality to `theTerms.push_back(Term(termString[i]));`, or `emplace_back` would likely be a more appropriate solution to the problem here.

Comment: @AtlasC1 that bit of code was exactly what I was looking for I appreciate the clarification. I am quite rusty with pointers in c++.